# Calculate the real integral using residue theorem $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2 + 16)^2}dx$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Calculate the real integral using residue theorem $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2 + 16)^2} \, dx$$

Can someone help with the solution?

Comment: If you show us how far you get before getting stuck, we can work out how best to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anticlockwise infinite semicircular contour $\Re z\ge0$ encloses one pole of the integrand, the second-order pole $4i$. So the integral is$$2\pi i\lim_{z\to4i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(z+4i)^2}=2\pi i\lim_{z\to4i}\frac{-2}{(z+4i)^3}=\frac{\pi}{128}.$$For what it's worth, you can solve this problem without the residue theorem, using $x=4\tan t$.